# Set document path in a excel cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA code where I set the path for the word file, so that I can use the word document as email body.
But instead I wanted to insert a cell reference in the code so that I don't have to change the code all the time.

Thank you in advance!!

Below is the code am using

```
Sub Email()
Dim oOutApp As Object
Dim oMailItem As Object
Dim oWordApp As Object
Dim oWordDoc As Object
Dim oMailWordDoc As Object
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range
Dim FileCell As Range
Dim rng As Range
With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With
Set sh = Sheets("details")
 On Error GoTo CleanUp
Set oWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set oWordDoc = oWordApp.documents.Open("...File path..")
oWordDoc.Content.copy
Set oOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
For Each cell In sh.Columns.Range("B3:B10000").cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
Set rng = sh.cells(cell.Row, 1).Range("I1:J1")
        If cell.Value Like "*" And _
           Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) > 0 Then
Set oMailItem = oOutApp.CreateItem(0)
With oMailItem
    .To = cell.Value
    .cc = cells(cell.Row, "C").Value  'sh.Columns.Range("C3").cells
    .Subject = cells(cell.Row, "F").Value
    .Body = ""
     For Each FileCell In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
           If Trim(FileCell) <> "" Then
               If Dir(FileCell.Value) <> "" Then
                 .Attachments.Add FileCell.Value
                  End If
                End If
               .Display
           Next FileCell
            Set oMailWordDoc = oOutApp.ActiveInspector.WordEditor
    Set editor = .GetInspector.WordEditor
    editor.Content.Paste
      .send
End With
End If
Next cell
Set oMailWordDoc = oOutApp.ActiveInspector.WordEditor
CleanUp:
oWordApp.Quit
Set oMailWordDoc = Nothing
Set oMailItem = Nothing
Set oOutApp = Nothing
Set oWordDoc = Nothing
Set oWordApp = Nothing
With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Post your current code so that we can suggest modifycation.

Comment: Have given my code @sixthsense

Comment: I don't see any path in your code.

Comment: Set oWordDoc = oWordApp.documents.Open("C:\...File path..") i will mention my path here @sixthsence

Comment: Set oWordDoc = oWordApp.documents.Open(Worksheets("YourSheetNameHere").Range("A1").Value)

Comment: Mention your sheet name and change A1 to your desired cell in the above lines

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if i understand you rigth. 
but i think what you are looking for is something like this:

```
strPath = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").value
```

so you can write the Path in the cell A1 inside the First sheet and the VBA Code will use this Path for the Word Document.

Comment: Thank you @Moosli will try this out.